# Switched servers, MySQL ORDER BY issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I just switched from XAMPP to [uniform server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) today.

This:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE date = '$year/$month/$day' ORDER BY roomNb ASC";
```

works fine for me under XAMPP. It retrieves the rooms with those dates and orders them nicely from 1 to X, in ascending order.

The same script under uniform server produces this:

```
9
10
11
12
14
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

What could be causing this behavior?

**EDIT**

See comment below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE date = '$year/$month/$day' ORDER BY roomNb ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo "$row['roomNb'] <br>";
}
```

**EDIT**

Screen of my table structure:

[image]

Comment: is `roomNb` an integer? Also, please start using a column list in your queries.

Comment: Show us the datatype of `roomNB`. Ideally the whole structure of `rooms`.

Comment: If you try the query in PHPMyAdmin, you have a correct result? Also, remove double quotes around variables: `echo $row['roomNb'] . " <br />";`

Comment: You're right I should have tried that first. Yes I get them in the right order in PHPMyAdmin. Why would PHP not take them in that order? That PHP script ordered them correctly with XAMPP.